# Loss of precision after passing a parameter

Tags: java, double, precision, long-integer

I have a long that holds a big value. Then I try to pass it as a parameter to a function, that takes double after which the precision is lost. Why is that and how can I avoid that?

```
long bigValue = 3038528443022066688L;
foo(bigValue);
 ...

foo(double value){
 System.out.printlin(value);
}
```

Actual result: 3.0385284430220667E18
Expected: the original value

I am aware that not every long can be represented as a double but how can I keep the original value?

Comment: "I am aware that not every long can be represented as a double but how can I keep the original value?". If your goal is to be able to represent every `long` value, then why don't use use `long` as the parameter type?

Comment: "I am aware that not every long can be represented as a double" Yeah. So don't use `double` or accept that this is what will happen.

Comment: How about BigInteger?

Comment: Don´t use a parameter of type **double**. The loss of precision is caused by the representation of the number in **long** and **double** types. A long has all of its 64 bits representing the number, whereas the double has only 53 bits to represent the mantissa.

Comment: Are you aware why you cannot represent any long as double? This has nothing to do with passing a parameter, it is merely a conversion from long to double.

Answer (score 1):

A double is a floatingpoint value. This implies that it  never holds an exact value. Any Floatingpoint has some precision, tollerance or error.

In other words a Floatingpoint is allways just an aproximation.
The aproximation *can* hit the exact value like any aproximarion *can* but still stays an aproximation.

This has important consequences: you cannot just feed doubles in a formula of a scientist. Trying so leads in general to unusable unreliable/wrong results. Instead you have to find a replacement formula that takes into account that it is an aproximation. E.g division and roots stabelize, differences of different sized values lead to errors and need scaling ...

With that in mind you got 3.0385284430220667E18 as an aproximation of 3038528443022066688 - which is a valid aproximation.

This happened when you told Java to create a double(plain: an aproximation) from your long(which was a "discrete" number and calculus needs to take that into acount: discrete mathematics or like Knuth calls it "concrete" ).

Answer (score 0):

It is just not possible to retain the mentionned value as a `double` in its full precision.

`3038528443022066688` has a binary precision of 62 bits. A `double`, however, has only a mantissa of (AFAIR) 53 bits. So 9 bits are lost. This cannot be avoided if you work with `double`.

If you can afford this, you can stay with `long`, otherwise you can use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`, whatever fits your needs best.